# Swift - How switch between storyboards with back button?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I'm in a storyboard and I need to go to another storyboard by tapping a button. Well, this I've already done, but I need to go back to previous storyboard. Here is my code:

```
func goContact() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FAQ", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactViewController")
    self.navigationController?.show(vc, sender: nil)
}
```

By tapping a button on my UITableViewCell (where I have a protocol), this function (goContact) is called and I switch to another storyboard (FAQ). But, how can I go back to main.storyboard?

I've already tried do this too:

```
func goContact() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FAQ", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContactViewController")
    self.navigationController?.show(vc, sender: nil)
    // self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    // self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should push your new view controller onto the navigation controller using push, like in your commented-out code. That will cause the new view controller to have a back button, which will pop it for you without needing any extra code.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Use only  `storyboard` property , it references to Main storyboard of the app or you can write it like `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

To go back after push do

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm in main.storyboard, and I need to go to ContactViewController (which is in FAQ.storyboard), so I need to put `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "FAQ", bundle: nil)`. And your code show me an error: `reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x167a3ff0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ContactViewController''`

Comment: ok then inside `ContactViewController`  you only need `popViewController`  to go back to the previous vc ,  navigation  between screens when using a navigationcontroller occurs with `push/pop`  has no relation to where the vc exists in terms of it's storyboard

Comment: may be inside some button action in `ContactViewController ` or default back button of the navigation

Comment: Ok, but this controller (ContactViewController) is called from another controllers. So, I can't put a button there. I'd like to use the IOS back button, the native button (in header).

Comment: then use `pushViewController` not `show` also the navigation should contain at least  2 vcs to be able to see default back button

Comment: I'm using `pushViewController `, but the back button is not showing.

Comment: navigation contains 2 vcs ? also make sure `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` ,  if not shown add a custom button

Comment: I think so. Contain the ContactViewController (where I want to go) and TrackingViewController (where I am). Where do I put `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false` ??

Comment: inside `TrackingViewController ` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197057/discussion-between-kim-ruan-and-sh-khan).